# can a line integral of domain $C$ be negative when $C$ is the boundary of the region in the upper half plane? ($y>0$)

Tags: calculus, integration

ok so here is the question:

evaluate $\oint \left(3y^2+e^{\cos x}\,dx\right) + \left(\sin y+5x^2\,dy\right)$, where $C$ is the boundary of the region in the upper half-plane ($y\ge 0$)between the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+y^2=b^2$ where $0\lt a\lt b$

note: the region can be expressed in polar coordinates $0\le\theta\le\pi$ and $a\le r \le b$  good time for Greens theorem?

I dont know if it is the right answer because it is negative.

first I took $\partial$$F_2$/$dx$ and got $10x$ then $\partial F_1/\partial y$ and got $6y$

I converted $\iint_D (10x-6y)\,dA$ to $\int_0^\pi\!\int_a^b(10r\cos\theta-6r\sin\theta)r\,drd\theta$

then when I integrated I got $-4b^3+4a^3$

Comment: Its e^cosx sorry i didnt know how to write the command

Comment: I've edited the question to fix the formatting. You can view the commands I used by right-clicking the formatted math and selecting "View math as"->"TeX commands"

Comment: sorry man i was editing it too so i didnt think it worked! @AlexBecker

Answer (score 1):

You used correctly the Green's Theorem for that line integral and your last result is also correct. In fact, we have $$\iint_D(Q_x-P_y)dA=\iint_D (10x-6y)$$ in which $P=3y^2+e^{\cos x},~~Q=\sin y+5x^2$

Comment: Nice confirmation and elaboration!